# Creation of many to many record through trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

When `review_date__c` on `BMCServiceDesk__KM_KnowledgeArticle__c` changes it should trigger the creation of a `BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c` record, subsequently it should create a record in the `BMCServiceDesk__KM_Knowledge_Incident_Link__c`object which links the `BMCServiceDesk__KM_KnowledgeArticle__c` and `BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c`together. I'm trying to achieve this writing a trigger, but line 8 says "expecting a semi-colon, found 'in'". Not being a developer I'm struggling to adapt the code to work.

```
Trigger createMTM on BMCServiceDesk__KM_KnowledgeArticle__c(After update){
list<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> lstIncidents = new list<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>();
list<Knowledge_Incident_Link__c> lstkrs = new list<Knowledge_Incident_Link__c>();

if(trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
    for(BMCServiceDesk__KM_KnowledgeArticle__c kr : trigger.new){
        if(kr.review_date__c != trigger.oldmap.get(kr.id).review_date__c){
            BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c in = new BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c();
            in.BMCServiceDesk__incidentDescription__c = kr.id;

            lstIncidents.add(in);

            BMCServiceDesk__KM_Knowledge_Incident_Link__c ki = new   BMCServiceDesk__KM_Knowledge_Incident_Link__c();
            ki.BMCServiceDesk__Knowledge_Article__c = kr.id;
            Ki.BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c = in.id;

            lstkrs.add(ki);
        }  
    }
    insert lstIncidents;
    insert lstkrs;
}
}
```

Object relationships below:[image]

Comment: what is the line number error tells?

Comment: BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c in = new BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c();

Comment: try to change the name of `in` to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration `in` is the problem. You can not use keywords which Salesforce uses in their syntax. However, it is not true in all cases.

Change the declaration `in` to some other value for ex: `incidentRec` in all the occurrences.

```
BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c incidentRec = new BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c(); // so on...
```